# How to use regex in SMLNJ

Tags: regex, smlnj

I want to input a string and then want to see whether it matches with a certain regex or not; if not I want to move on to another regex till all my regexs are exhausted. For eg.,suppose I have following 3 regexs

- regex_1 = [a-zA-Z]*
- regex_2 = [0-9]*
- regex_3 = (1tom|2jerry)

Now suppose that the desired string is :

```
- val str_input="7569"
```

I want to check str_input first with regex_1;if it does not match then try with regex_2;if it does not match then finally try with regex_3.
The problem is that how to use SMLNJ for this purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the regular expression library that SML/NJ provides. Its documentation can be found here: http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/regexp-lib-part.html

As a small getting started example, here's what you need to do. First you need to tell SML/NJ that you want to use the regexp library. You can accomplish that using a `.cm` file (cm comes from Compilation Manager and it's sort of a Makefile for SML/NJ):

#### sources.cm

```ml
group is
  $/basis.cm      (* Load standard functions and modules. *)
  $/regexp-lib.cm (* Load the regexp library.             *)
  main.sml        (* Load our own source file.            *)
```

Now we can use the regexp library. Unfortunately, it's not really straightforward, because it makes use of functors and readers, but basically, what you need is the `RE.match` function, which accepts a list of pairs, where the first element is a regex and the second is a function that's called when that regexp is matched. Using this list of pairs, the `RE.match` function will walk the input string until it finds a match, at which point it will call the function associated with the regexp that matched at that point. The result of that function is the result of the whole `RE.match` call.

#### main.sml

```ml
structure Main =
  struct
    (**
     * RE is a module created by calling the module-level function (functor)
     * RegExpFn (Fn comes from functor), with two module arguments.
     *
     * The first argument, called P, is the syntax used to write regular
     * expressions in. In this particular case, it's the Awk syntax, which
     * is the only syntax provided by SML/NJ right now.
     *
     * The second argument, called E, is the RegExp engine used behind the
     * scenes to compile and execute the syntax. In this particular case
     * I've opted for ThompsonEngine, which implements Ken Thompson's
     * matching algorithm. Other options are BackTrackEngine and DfaEngine.
     *)
    structure RE = RegExpFn(
      structure P = AwkSyntax
      structure E = ThompsonEngine
      (* structure E = BackTrackEngine *)
      (* structure E = DfaEngine *)
    )

    fun main () =
      let
        (**
         * A list of (regexp, match function) pairs. The function called by
         * RE.match is the one associated with the regexp that matched.
         *
         * The match parameter is described here:
         *   http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/match-tree.html
         *)
        val regexes = [
          ("[a-zA-Z]*",   fn match => ("1st", match)),
          ("[0-9]*",      fn match => ("2nd", match)),
          ("1tom|2jerry", fn match => ("3rd", match))
        ]
        val input = "7569"
      in
        (**
         * StringCvt.scanString will traverse the `input` string and apply
         * the result of `RE.match regexes` to each character in the string.
         *
         * It's sort of a streaming matching process. The end result, however,
         * depends on your implementation above, in the match functions.
         *)
        StringCvt.scanString (RE.match regexes) input
      end
  end
```

You can now use it like this from the command line:

```
$ sml sources.cm
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Sun Jan  3 23:12:46 2016]
[scanning sources.cm]
[library $/regexp-lib.cm is stable]
[parsing (sources.cm):main.sml]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
- Main.main ();
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
val it = SOME ("2nd",Match ({len=4,pos=0},[]))
  : (string * StringCvt.cs Main.RE.match) option
```

#### Documentation

- [`REGEXP.match`](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/regexp-sig.html#SIG:REGEXP.match:VAL)
- [`MatchTree`](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/match-tree.html)
- [`StringCvt`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/string-cvt.html)